# Proof that derives Newton's law of gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I was wondering if it is possible to derive Newton's law of universal gravitation, without utilizing Kepler's 3rd law. I have found [many proofs](http://burro.cwru.edu/academics/Astr221/Gravity/gravity.htm) that use this type of proof. I read [somewhere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/380177/277221) that Kepler's laws predated Newton to discover the fundamental formula that Newton used for the law, but I was wondering what would've been the proof for this formula if Newton discovered this without Kepler's law.

Comment: Physical laws don’t have proofs. Physics isn’t a branch of mathematics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did Newton discover the universal law of gravitation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139268/)